# Run program on AWS server from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, server

I am not sure this can be done but I have installed a Winforms application on an AWS server. I want to allow users to run the program but not by going through the rigmarole of using RDC and then running the program when connected that way. I looked at this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-essentials/use/use-remote-web-access-in-windows-server-essentials#BKMK_Connect

But when I tried connecting in the browser I got an error "this web page can't be found". Ultimately I want the user to have an icon on their desktop that they click on, it connects to the server, runs the program for them to then use. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a potential use case for [Amazon AppStream](https://aws.amazon.com/appstream2/) where the desktop applications run on a remote, managed server and you interact with them from your browser.

You can [try out sample applications](https://aws.amazon.com/appstream2/try-sample-applications/) like FreeCAD or Eclipse.